# What will be the radius of the common circle formed by intersection of two spheres of radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ that cut orthogonally.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, spheres

Two spheres of radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ intersect each other orthogonally. Prove that the circle formed by the intersection of the two spheres has a radius 
$$\frac{r_1 r_2}{\sqrt{r_1^{2} + r_2^{2}}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT.

See below a section of the spheres, passing through their centers $A$ and $B$. They intersect each other orthogonally if radii $AC$ and $BC$ are perpendicular.

It follows that $ABC$ is a right triangle with legs $r_1$ and $r_2$. And its altitude $CH$ is the radius of the intersection circle.

[image]

Comment: How do we show that CH is perpendicular to AB? Thanks.

Comment: @R_D If $D$ is the other intersection, then triangles $ABC$ and $ABD$ are congruent. It follows that $\angle CBH=\angle DBH$: triangles $BCH$ and $BDH$ are then also congruent. Hence $\angle BHC=\angle BHD$.

Comment: I referred to your sketch in my answer. Hope OK. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Aretino's sketch considering similar right triangles

$$CH= h ;\,CA= r_1;\,CB= r_2;\, \angle ACH= \angle HBC= \theta \,$$

$$ \cos \theta = \frac{h}{r_1}  ;\,\sin \theta=\frac{h}{r_2} ; $$

The result is arrived at by eliminating $\theta.$